# How to make 2 different redirects to the URL as 0 using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

"Even if the URL in the address contains a category URL ([www.domain.com/sample-category-url](http://www.domain.com/sample-category-url)), it redirects to detail.php.

How can I make these two URLs recognize each other and open detail.php if the value is a URL, or open category.php if the value is category_url?

NOTE: The URLs should have no spaces in the domain name. ([www.domain.com/sample-category-url](http://www.domain.com/sample-category-url)) or ([www.domain.com/sample-url](http://www.domain.com/sample-url)) should lead to (detail.php)."

Please note that the translation is based on the context provided, and some technical terms may have specific translations depending on the programming language or framework being used.

```
# Detail page redirection.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/kategori/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/_.]+)/?$ detay.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]


# Category page redirection
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/_.]+)/?$ kategori.php?category_url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I tried manipulating the URL structure many times, but it didn't work.

Comment: I can't make sense of what you are trying to ask here, you'll need to clarify what the actual situation is. _"How can I make these two URLs recognize each other"_ - okay, take a step back - you have shown _one_ URL so far up to this point, so what are you even talking about right now? _"and open detail.php if the value is a URL"_ - and what does _that_ mean; _which_ value "is a URL"? And you are testing that the URL path does not start with `/kategori/` in your first block - but you have not even given any example URL that would contain this.

Comment: "The value named 'url' is my topic URL value. When redirecting, I use it like this: <a href="<?=$topic['url']?>">. Similarly, the value named 'category_url' is for the category. When redirecting, I use it like this: <a href="<?=$category['category_url']?>">. I want these two incoming values to be recognized by htaccess, and if the value is 'category_url', it should go to www.site.com/category_url as kategori.php. Likewise, htaccess should recognize the value again, and if the value is 'url', it should go to www.site.com/url as detay.php."

Comment: Okay fine, but how can such a topic URL be distinguished from a category URL? You need a _pattern_ that allows you to be able to recognize which is which, how else could this possibly work?

Comment: Can't I make htaccess understand and differentiate this?

Comment: Based on _what_? You have no access to your database at this point - where I'd assume you would find the actual information, whether the requested slug is a topic or a category? Those are your two options: Either use a distinct URL _pattern_ that allows you to differentiate between the two in the .htaccess already - or rewrite to _one_ PHP script, which will go look up the slug in the database, and then decides how to proceed, depending on whether it was a topic or a category.

Comment: Hello! I apologize for my poor English. However, I still couldn't understand how to do the redirection with htaccess. Isn't there a way? I mean, can't we differentiate between the <a href="<?=$konu['url']?>"> and <a href="<?=$kategori['kategori_url']?>"> sent URLs in htaccess and redirect them to detail.php if the "url" value is present or to kategori.php if the "kategori_url" value is present?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254796/discussion-between-ilkertncr-and-cbroe).

Comment: Okay, say my site works exactly the same as yours. One of my URLs is `/foobar`- now you tell me please, is that a topic, or a category ...? What, you say you can't do that, based on the information available to you at this point? Well then how do you expect the server to be able to do it in .htaccess?

Comment: _"if the "url" value is present or to kategori.php if the "kategori_url" value is present?"_ - the server doesn't see any of the _variable names_ you used when you created those links, when you process the incoming request in .htaccess - it sees only what the _values_ were. So if those values follow some sort of _pattern_ that allows to distinguish between a topic and a category, _then_ it can be done in .htaccess, otherwise not.

Comment: If you had, example, `/topic/foo` and `/category/bar` as your URLs - then those could be differentiated, based on that prefix. But if you have just `/foo` and `/bar`, how would you tell which is supposed to be which?

Comment: I understand what you said! So, you mean that additional parameterless parsing cannot be done with htaccess, right? Did I understand correctly? In other words, if I want to redirect based on the domain like 0 (www.domain.com/url - category_url), I need to perform a check in the database and based on the result, I either need to redirect or include a file. Did I get it wrong?

Comment: _"So, you mean that additional parameterless parsing cannot be done with htaccess, right?"_ - you do not _have_ anything else to parse at this point, but the incoming request URL. If you do not want to add _additional_ information to those URLs in the first place, then yes, you will have to make the decision, whether you are dealing with a topic or a category, in PHP.

Comment: You're very welcome! Of course, if you encounter any issues with pagination while implementing the solution, feel free to reach out to me again. I'll be happy to assist you. Thank you for your kind words! I'm here to help, so don't hesitate to ask if you need any further assistance. Good luck with your project!

Comment: @CBroe "Hello! Thank you again for your help. I need your assistance one more time. I am checking the URL coming to index.php, and if it is a category, I call the category page; if it is a topic, I call the detail page. However, I couldn't figure out how to implement pagination. My current .htaccess is:                           
  RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/_.]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: _"However, I couldn't figure out how to implement pagination."_ - I can't tell what that means, you'll need to be more specific.

Comment: Hello. I apologize for my bad English and the sometimes nonsensical things that my keyboard and I produce together. I apologize again for mistakenly saying, "You're very welcome! Of course, if you encounter any issues with pagination while implementing the solution, feel free to reach out to me again."

Comment: @CBroe Let me explain the system I have built so that you can understand how to implement pagination. In my index.php, I have set up if loops to redirect the incoming URL value to index.php, where I determine whether it is a category or a topic. If there is no URL, it loads the homepage (anasayfam.php), and if there is a URL, I require the corresponding category or detail page. Now, how should I follow a pagination logic in this case?

Comment: Same as you would have handled it before ...? You must be passing some page number parameter via the URL, I suppose? So extract the value of that then, and show the corresponding range of your topic or category content ...